# How to escape a string with additional paramer?

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am trying to escape a string and it currently looks like this:

```
... onclick="anotherfunction(\'bla\',\'bla\'); myfunctionhere(\'/path1/path2/\'' + val.param1 + '\', \'' + val.param2 + '\', \'' + val.param3 + '\')";
```

Something is still wrong with it because val.param1 is there but still with an additional ' in front.

Lets say val.param1 is 4711 then the first part of myfunctionhere is being renders as

```
/path1/path2/'4711
```

How do I solve this? Removing the second ' does not help.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the single quotes `\'`

Comment: Generating JavaScript embedded in HTML by mashing strings together is really error prone and hard to debug. Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Are you doing this in JavaScript or HTML?

Comment: If you really have to do it with strings, template literals will simplify it.

Comment: @Barmar — Yeah, but having special characters in the variables you drop into the template is still likely to cause problems.

Comment: General problems with your whole approach aside, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmer in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got it working right now:

```
... onclick="anotherfunction(\'bla\',\'bla\'); myfunctionhere(\'\/path1\/path2\/' + val.param1 + '\', \'' + val.param2 + '\', \'' + val.param3 + '\')";
```